# unable to user header('Location: ../abc.php');

Tags: php

When I use `header('Location: ../abc.php');` it doesn't work, but it works when I write `header('Location: http://folder_name/abc.php');`. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Have you enabled error display? Did you get any error?

Comment: if i use header('Location: ../abc.php'); it simply redirects to xampp own dashboard page. why so?

Comment: Use absolute URL.

Comment: Because `..` takes you one directory back.

Comment: In case of absolute URL, if another person will clone my code then he has to make several changes.

Comment: Make CONSTANTs then (like in your config file) for absolute URL and use it in every place so that whenever someone wants to change your code location (s)he will have to make changes only in CONSTANT... This is the standard approach.

Comment: And regarding relative path in `location`, it actually works well. In your case, if it is not working then check your .htaccess or virtual host or php.ini path settings if you are using any of it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It would be very helpful if you could add details on what "it doesn't work" means, and also some details on how your webserver is configured etc."

Answer (score 0):

This will cause some literal whitespace to be sent as output, preventing you from making subsequent header calls.

HTTP/1.1 requires an absolute URI as an argument to Location: including the scheme, hostname, and absolute path, but some clients accept relative URIs. You can usually use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` and `dirname()` to make an absolute URI from a relative one yourself: